# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error when i'm implementing footer within recycler view.

This is how i have done it. I was using two types for showing different views in list, but something is not set well in method `getItemCount()` or maybe when i'm getting position of clicked item model in list.

This is what i have so far:

```
private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER = 1;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers == null ? 0 : mUsers.size() + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isFooterPosition(position)) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isFooterPosition(int position) {
    return position == mUsers.size() + 1;
}

private User getUser (int position) {
    return mUsers.get(position - 1); // Here i'm getting an error mentioned in title
}
```

Edit:

```
if (holder instanceof UserHolder) {
        final User user = getUser(position);
        UserHolder userViewHolder = (UserHolder) holder;

        userViewHolder.tvUserName.setText(user.getName());
        userViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
            }
        });
    } else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
        FooterViewHolder footerViewHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Lato-Thin.ttf");
        footerViewHolder.mButton.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
```

I have some items for normal holder view in list and one item for footer view.

Comment: And what should be the result of `getUser(0)`? Btw: that doesn't doesn't look like a possible `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` source. More like `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I have created one method for testing purposes which will insert 20 elements in list.

Answer (score 3):

`mUsers.get(position - 1);` will crash when the `position` is 0 because you're looking for the item at index `-1` which is invalid.

If you're adding a footer, which will be present after all of the previous items, then do you need do the substraction?

- Position 0 => User 0
- Position 1 => User 1
- Position N => User N
- Position N + 1 => Footer

It might be better to just return `mUsers.get(position)`.

Edit: There's another small issue:

Here's an issue:

```
private boolean isFooterPosition(int position) {
    return position == mUsers.size() + 1;
}
```

`mUsers.size()` is 20, so users will have positions 0-19.
`isFooterPosition` should return true for 20 (users size + 1). However, that will return `false` because the footer is at position `21`.

Thus, you have a spot (`20`) that is completely invalid.

```
private boolean isFooterPosition(int position) {
    return position == mUsers.size();
}
```

Comment: If i set like that, i will get this error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 20`

Comment: I updated my answer with the fix to the footer position.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can modify `getUser()` method like following:

```
private boolean isValidPos(int position){
    return position >= 0 && position < mUsers.size();
}

private User getUser (int position) {
    if (isFooterPosition(position)) return null;

    return isValidPos(position) ? mUsers.get(position) : null; 
}
```

Comment: This modification gives me an error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 20, size is 20`

Comment: Sorry, i missed to check valid position. I've just edit the answer

Comment: Thank you for your trouble, but i have already found a solution.

Comment: could you share it :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see exactly what you want to do, but, as someone said before me, the error is in `mUsers.get(position - 1);`, because it's gonna search for a negative index if `position == 0`.

So, if you really need the subtraction, you can do like this:

```
private User getUser (int position) {
    if(position != 0)
        return mUsers.get(position - 1);
    else
        return mUsers.get(position);
}
```

But, as you can see, for `position == 0`, it will return the **same output** as `position == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and i have also extended `RecyclerView` with one more `typeview` for showing one view where there is no item:

First i have declared these variables in my adapter:

```
public static final int COUNT_FOOTER   = 1;
public static final int COUNT_NO_ITEMS = 1;

private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM    = 0;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER  = 1;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_NO_ITEM = 2;
```

After that i have define three view types for my list:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (!mUsers.isEmpty()) {
            if (position < mUsers.size()) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
            }
        } else {
            if (position == 0) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_NO_ITEM;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (!mUsers.isEmpty()) {
        return mUsers.size() + COUNT_FOOTER;
    } else {
        return COUNT_NO_ITEMS + COUNT_FOOTER;
    }
}

private User getUser (int position) {
    return mUsers.get(position);
}
```